# How to display a Set <String> in a certain number of lines

Tags: java, hashset

I copied lines of a file into a `HashSet` named `lines`. I have a `display()` method that takes one `int` called `numberOfLines`.

```
public void display(int numberOfLines) {
}
```

I want to use this method to display the Set with the specified number of lines.
Would I have to convert the set to a string and then work with the string? Please show me how I would do this.

Comment: Use an iterator (obtained from the set) and a counter to print the strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the HashSet to print the elements,  and print a new line every lines.size () / numberOfLines elements.